# "Identifier expected" error when adding elements of ArrayList into Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, identifier

So I seem to be getting an "identifier expected" error when I try to add the elements of the ArrayList Inventory into the Array InventoryArr[].

```
List<String> Inventory = new ArrayList<String>();
String InventoryArr[] = new String[Inventory.size()];
InventoryArr = Inventory.toArray(InventoryArr);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Unrelated, but it'd be easier to read if you followed Java naming conventions.

Comment: @JonSkeet-It is not a duplicate!

Comment: Please be very specific and include the minimal amount of code necessary to recreate the error. With this code located in an appropriate place in a source file it works just fine. You probably have the `InventoryArr = ...` somewhere not in a method.

Comment: @DaveNewton The code is located between the class declaration and the first method. Should I make any changes?

Comment: @ShreyashChaudhari Yes, you should.

Comment: @shekharsuman I disagree; it's almost certainly the exact same issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton-Yeah,now I agree. Issue is same,but,one couldn't decide unless more information is provided in the question!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't give such an error when i run the exact same code.
Here is my code:

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> Inventory = new ArrayList<String>();
        String InventoryArr[] = new String[Inventory.size()];
        InventoryArr = Inventory.toArray(InventoryArr);
    }
}
```